# DatagridView particular Columns Search Value and Select that cell without Textbox

Tags: c, datagridview

My Name Hiren.
I have to make Simple Datagridview In C#. ( Starting For Developing.)
I have search value in particular columns Used textbox and button. (its run fine.)

but I will search Value Directly Without any Textbox.

I have attached an image for this result.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObIYz.png)

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();   //or restore rows backcolor to default
            for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().StartsWith(textBox2.Text, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true; //It is also possible to color the row backgroud


                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

but I will no used textbox. simple click columns and type then cursor selected this value who I type.

please help me.

Comment: Please provide specific details on what you have tried so far the error encountered.  From the question it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve and what your issue is.

Comment: This Code Not A Problem This Run fine but I have like a simple method for search value simple I click one column any cell then type 'Bapa' then selected who's cell first word 'b' then whos cell first 'ba' then 'bap' then 'Bapa' fine i have type 'BAPA' THEN 'SELECT cell start 'bapa'.